# Editing shapefiles

Tags: editing

I have a heavy editing job coming up and I was thinking of creating different version of the same shapefile and have multiple people work on it. What is the best way or is there a way to check an edited shapefile versus the existing shapefile for QA / QC purposes.

Comment: what type of geodatabases are you using?  can you setup it up in a versioned environment?  Here is a nice overview of it if you dont already know http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0110/versioning101.html

Comment: Load the shapefile into a database and use the database for multi-editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable many editors to work on a single dataset or group of datasets, you can use geodatabase versioning. Have a read of the related [ArcGIS help article](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_version/003n000000tq000000/) for a complete how-to. In a nutshell, you'll be able to have multiple users editing data, and edits which are submitted to the geodatabase can be moderated if need be.